# Swift: MapView geocodeAddressString doesn't work after the Map view disappears/reappears

Tags: ios, swift

I am doing a project that is like this.

Have a text box/button that takes a zip code and pass the zip code to a segue to the map view controller that shows the zip code region on the map. The entire setup is behind a navigation controller so that I could go back and try another zip code in the previous view.

The problem is that the map view plots the zip code properly the first time, but then when I go back and enter another zip code in the previous view controller, the map view doesn't set the region to the new zip code properly, instead it shows a new map view with the default region in the simulator. See the below code

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

    var searchZipCode:String! = "95110" //used by other segues to set zipcode to show on this page
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    var dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create()

        dispatch_group_enter(dispatchGroup)
        self.plotZipCodeInMap(self.searchZipCode)

        dispatch_group_notify(dispatchGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            print("Zip code plotted.")
    }

    func plotZipCodeInMap(zipCode:String) {
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(zipCode, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
            print("Zip code = \(zipCode)")
            if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                print("Successfully decoded the zip code..")
                let coordinate = placemark.location?.coordinate
                let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate!.latitude, longitude: coordinate!.longitude)
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.04, longitudeDelta: 0.04))
                self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
                dispatch_group_leave(self.dispatchGroup)
            }
        })
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("Location updated..")
        let locations = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locations!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: locations!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.075, longitudeDelta: 0.075))
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

}

The problem is when I go back to the first view in the navigation controller and hit another zip code, the map view seems to be entering the plotZipCodeInMap method properly, but then it doesn't print the line

"Successfully decoded the zip code.."

which means there is some trouble in getting the placemark the second time. Not sure what could be the issue here. The variables are all local and I expect them to behave no differently when clicking back button (the map view disappears) and the view is shown again with another zip code set based on my input.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it has nothing to do with view disappearing/reappearing, but to do with the number of geocoding calls I make. When I print the error, it's all clear - [kCLErrorDomain error 2 after geocoding repeatedly with CLGeocoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867422/kclerrordomain-error-2-after-geocoding-repeatedly-with-clgeocoder)